# Using AppleScript to replace Text in an HTM File via TextEdit

Tags: applescript, textedit

AppleScript newb here....

Trying to setup an applescript that will replace a few lines of code from and .htm file

**This is ugly, but works:**

```
tell application "Finder"
  activate
          tell application "System Events"
  key down {command}
  keystroke "a"
  key up {command}
          end tell
end tell

tell application "Finder"
  activate
          set fileCount to count files in front window
          set fileCountAlert to fileCount
end tell
tell application "System Events"
          tell process "Finder"
                    tell menu bar 1
                              tell menu bar item "File"
                                        tell menu "File"
                                                  tell menu item "Open With"
                                                            tell menu "Open With"
                                                                      click menu item "TextEdit"
                                                            end tell
                                                  end tell
                                        end tell
                              end tell
                    end tell

          end tell
  delay 3
end tell

repeat until fileCount = 0

          tell application "TextEdit"
  activate
                    tell application "System Events"

  key down {command}
  keystroke "f"
  key up {command}
  --delay 1
                              keystroke "BORDER=1"
                              delay 0.5
  keystroke tab
  keystroke tab

                              keystroke "BORDER=0"
                              delay 0.5
  key down {command}
  keystroke "w"
  key up {command}
                              delay 0.5
                    end tell

          end tell

          set fileCount to (fileCount - 1)
end repeat

tell application "Finder"
          display dialog "Completed Adjusting " & fileCountAlert & " files."
end tell
```

**I also tried using something like this.... but this thing didn't work at all....**

```
set the search_document to (choose file)
replaceText("BORDER=1", "BORDER=0", search_document)

on replaceText(search_string, replacement_text, this_document)
          tell application "TextEdit"
  open this_document
                    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
                    set this_text to the text of the front document as list
                    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_text
                    set the text of the front document to (this_text as string)
  close this_document saving yes
          end tell
end replaceText
```

**Lastly... I tried figuring out how to click buttons in applescript using something like this:**

```
      tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "TextEdit"
  click button "All" of scroll area of window "3.htm"
                    end tell
          end tell
```

**BUT - I keep getting errors here.   I'm using a UIElementInspector app but no luck.

Wondering if anyone has anny quick help suggestions?**

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a test file:

```
set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set myData to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
    set newData to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " | sed 's/BORDER=1/BORDER=0/g' > " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST**, you can script TextEdit without emulating keyboard events but communicating directly with the application.

You can open a file, get the text into a string, work the string, put the string again as the content of the opened file and save.

Open the TextEdit dictionary from AppleScript Editor to see what's available.

**BUT** for what you need to do (open a file, make changes, save) **you don't even need TextEdit**.

You can load the file directly into your script, edit and save. And it will be much faster:

Set the path to your file into **theFile** and open the file into a string

```
set fref to a reference to file theFile
set theText to read fref as string
```

You have the content into **theText** ready for processing.

You'll find pleny of tutorials on working with strings with AppleScript; just Google around...

Assuming you want to just substitute some text use that function

```
on Substitute(s, f, r)
    if f = "" then return s
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to f
    set theTextItems to text items of s
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to r
    set s to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return s
end Substitute
```

It takes the string **s** search for **f** replace with **r** returns the resulting string.

Finally you want to save your text.

Set again **theFile** to the file path of your file (or leave the original).

Note that if the file exists and is writeable it will be silently overwritten.

```
set fref to a reference to file theFile
open for access fref with write permission
set eof of fref to 0
write theText to fref starting at eof as string
close access fref
```

**Last note:** the path to the file **theFile** must be specified in the *Applescript way*

For example

```
set theFile to "MyMacHD:Users:Paolo:Desktop:myTextFile.txt"
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. As my text included utf-8 characters, I replaced 'string' with '«class utf8»'.